# How can I report a change in Google Maps that is not a road or a place?

Tags: google-maps

Last year a nearby lake was filled in, and converted into a green space with grass, trees, and walkways.  However, this lake is still on Google Maps.  I decided to report it to them, but it seems I can only report a missing business, or make changes to roads.

When I open the menu, I see "Add a missing place" and "Send feedback".  "Add a missing place" isn't what I want to do, because I want to *remove* something, not add it.

[image: Screenshot showing Google Maps main menu]

Clicking "Send feedback" gives more options, of which "Edit the map" seems most promising.  However, selecting this option only allows me to choose a road or place that is in error.  I cannot select a body of water.  When I click on the lake, it instead selects the nearest road.

[image: Screenshot showing "Send feedback" menu]

I considered the generic "Other feedback", but it seems more for reporting issues with the Google Maps website itself, and not the map data.

[image: Screenshot showing "Edit the map" menu]

It's possible that, because bodies of water generally do not change, Google doesn't accept requests to edit them.  However, it could be that I'm just missing a button somewhere.  I figured I'd ask here as a last resort before I give up.

**Is it possible to report a change in a body of water to Google Maps?**